# How does raft deal with log in this scenario?

Tags: algorithm, distributed, raft

[image]

Assume d is elected as an leader in the above picture, how will it deal with the log with index 11 and 12. In my opinion, it should delete the two logs, but I don't find any clues in the raft paper about how to deal logs like the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (d) is elected leader, then it will replicate its log to the followers, it won't remove the items at index 11 & 12. See section 5.3 on log replication in the [raft paper](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf) where it says

> In Raft, the leader handles inconsistencies by forcing the followers’
>   logs to duplicate its own. This means that conflicting entries in
>   follower logs will be overwritten with entries from the leader’s log.

The rules around leader election ensure that this is a safe decision to make.

Comment: logs at 11 & 12 are not committed yet, to my understanding, raft will not re-commit logs that are not committed yet in previous iterms.

Comment: they won't be committed until the leader has replicated them, but the leader will replicate prior terms when it becomes leader. Once the log items have been replicated to enough node, those entries will be committed.

Comment: in section 5.4.2 of raft paper, figure 8 illustrates an example, by commiting log entry of previous terms, it may overwrite existing log entries that committed already by previous leader, so I think leader d will not replicate logs 11 & 12 and commit them.

Comment: the leader won't delete log entries from its own log, so it has to replicate them and then commit them.

Comment: Well.  Then the log would be different between scenario that (d) becomes leader and scenario that  (a) becomes leader?

Comment: Yes, if (a) was elected leader the resulting log would be different [but only for log entries that were uncommitted at the time of the election]